# How to convert a boolean array into a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am a beginner, and I want to know is it possible to convert a boolean array into a matrix in NumPy?

For example, we have a boolean array `a` like this:

```
a = [[False],
     [True],
     [True],
     [False],
     [True]]
```

And, we turn it into the following matrix:

```
m = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I mean the array to be the diagonal of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.diagflat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagflat.html#numpy.diagflat) which *creates a two-dimensional array with the flattened input as a diagonal*:

```
np.diagflat(np.array(a, dtype=int))

#[[0 0 0 0 0]
# [0 1 0 0 0]
# [0 0 1 0 0]
# [0 0 0 0 0]
# [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

[Working example](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/07aeba3e.py)